# SQL Adding three separate tables to an email

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to send out an email with two seprate tables.
How do I do that?

Adding sample data, per someone's request.

This is what the email should look like

Items

```
Item  Price
Apples 1.25
Oranges 2.24
Banana 0.29
```

Sales

```
Month  Item  Sold
Feb  Apples $5.00
Feb  Oranges $10.00
```

Here is the code.  I had to comment out the if statement and delete a begin for it to compile without errors.

```
    Declare @nvMessage nvarchar(1000)
       Declare @nvSubject nvarchar(1000)
       Declare @nvQuery nvarchar(4000)
        DECLARE @tabdata nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @table nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @tableHTML nvarchar(max)
       Declare @iWidth int
       Set @iWidth = 4000
       Set @nvSubject = 'Month End Report'

        Declare @MonthBegin datetime
        Declare @MonthEnd datetime
        Set @MonthBegin = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, 0)
        Set @MonthEnd = DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 SET @tableHTML =  
                N'<h2><font face="Calibri">Report: ' + '</font></h2>' + 
                N'<table border="1" rules="none" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="-1"><font face="Calibri" size=2>' + 
                N'<tr>' +
                N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1">Table Field you want to display</th>' +
                N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1"> Another Table Field you want to display</th>' +
                N'</tr>' + 
                CAST
                (
                (
                    SELECT * FROM ITEMS     
                    FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE  
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ) +'</table>' + '<hr color = "black"> </hr>'


--IF
--  (
--    SELECT
--        COUNT(*)
--    FROM 
--        table2 
--   ) > 0

-- if there is data in the second table then show it. If not dont. 

   SET @tableHTML = @tableHTML +
                N'<h2><font face="Calibri">Report: ' + '</font></h2>' + 
                N'<table border="1" rules="none" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="-1"><font face="Calibri" size=2>' + 
                N'<tr>' +
                N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1">Table Field you want to display</th>' +
                N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1"> Another Table Field you want to display</th>' +
                N'</tr>' + 
                CAST
                (
                (
            SELECT * FROM SALES

                    FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE  
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ) +'</table>' + '<hr color = "black"> </hr>'


-- then send out your mail 

BEGIN  

              SET @nvMessage = 'Month End  Report'
              EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail_mod
                     @recipients = @nvRecipients,
                     @subject = @nvSubject,
                     @body = @tableHTML,
                     @body_format = 'HTML'
END
```

Now I have too much code and it wants me to add more text. 
Now I have too much code and it wants me to add more text. 
Now I have too much code and it wants me to add more text. 
Now I have too much code and it wants me to add more text.

Comment: Any Sample data would be useful

Comment: I would urge you to read your question and ask yourself if you could answer this based only on the details posted. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: My suggestion is way off topic, but if you want to send reports. I would suggest SSRS and schedule it. You're email will be much more professional looking and you can control better what they see (do they need keys for example)

Comment: How do I do that with SSRS?

Comment: I'm just trying to throw two completely separate tables into one email.  Not joined, but separate.  I think this is a fairly simple thing to do but I can't find how.

Comment: Best bet is to put the whole body of the email in HTML, and then send it. Here is [one example](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1465444-279-1.aspx), and a [second](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4032/generate-html-formatted-emails-from-sql-server/) of what that would look like.

Comment: Thank you.  I have it set up but I'm stuck.  I updated my original question, and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use an HTML table to do this. This will create an email with multiple tables.

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

If
  (
   SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
   FROM 
        #TABLE_YOU_WANT_DATA_FROM 
  ) = 0 

BEGIN
    SET @tableHTML = @NewLineChar
END 
    SET @tableHTML =  
                    N'<h2><font face="Calibri">Report: ' + '</font></h2>' + 
                    N'<table border="1" rules="none" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="-1"><font face="Calibri" size=2>' + 
                    N'<tr>' +
                    N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1">field1</th>' +
                    N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1">field2</th>' +
                    N'</tr>' + 
                    CAST
                    (
                    (
                        SELECT

                            td = x1,'' AS [field1],
                            td = x2 ,'' AS [field2]
                        FROM
                            TABLE_YOU_WANT_DATA_FROM             
                        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE  
                ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ) +'</table>' + '<hr color = "black"> </hr>'
    END

    IF
      (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM 
            table2 
       ) > 0

    -- if there is data in the second table then show it. If not dont. 
    BEGIN
       SET @tableHTML = @tableHTML +
                    N'<h2><font face="Calibri">Report: ' + '</font></h2>' + 
                    N'<table border="1" rules="none" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="-1"><font face="Calibri" size=2>' + 
                    N'<tr>' +
                    N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1">field1</th>' +
                    N'<th bgcolor="#C5D9F1">field2</th>' +
                    N'</tr>' + 
                    CAST
                    (
                    (
                        SELECT

                            td = x1,'' AS [field1],
                            td = x2 ,'' AS [field2]
                        FROM
                            TABLE_YOU_WANT_DATA_FROM             
                        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE  
                ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ) +'</table>' + '<hr color = "black"> </hr>'
    END

    -- then send out your mail 

    BEGIN  

                  SET @nvMessage = 'Month End  Report'
                  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail_mod
                         @recipients = @nvRecipients,
                         @subject = @nvSubject,
                         @body = @tableHTML,
                         @body_format = 'HTML'
    END
```

Comment: Very impressive

Comment: Thanks. This works but it's showing up as two columns.  Nothing is in the second column.  The first column is showing up as Apples1.250000000e+002

Comment: I would have to see an example of what your code looks like. This will work, I use this when I need to email table data.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why but it's not working 100%.  Can someone take a look? Instead of having two columns the data is all smooshed into the first column.  I updated my original post.  Thank you.

Comment: This is because you are doing a SELECT * rather than specifically selecting the fields that you want.  Select td = item,'' AS [item], td = price,'' AS [price].

Comment: Thanks. I am not doing a Select *.  It's just two columns.  Select A, B, From MyTable WHERE CONVERT (DATE, Scheduled) >= CONVERT (DATE, @MonthBegin)

Comment: @CNL In the code you have posted you are doing a Select * where you should be selecting the table data.

Comment: Sorry I was just trying to make it quickly.  My select statement is rather long.  I was trying to simplify it. It is only two columns.

Comment: Do you need the whole thing?  I'm happy to provide it. I just don't know why it's concatenating the data.

Comment: If you could update your code in your original example I could take a look. I am pretty sure that you aren't selecting the table data correctly.  The reason I say this is based on your code example it looks like you are doing Select * from sales and Select * from items.

Answer (score 0):

Poor solution, but this is as close as you can get using send_dbmail. It only works if you have the same columns in both tables:

SET @nvquery = 'SELECT * FROM #TME1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #TME1 WHERE 1=2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #TME2'

Comment: Thank you. That would work but I need two separate tables.  The columns and rows are different.

Comment: You could have an umbrella of Col1, Col2, Col3 etc. and first add table 1 column names as a row of data, then map the data to cols 1-n, then do the same for table 2