# SQL Sent out jobs with email

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

What is the best way to use scheduled jobs to send out an email? Right now the way we do it is difficult.  Attaching Excel spreadsheets only works if it's a full moon, and straight data just looks cryptic.  Is there a better way?  I am using SSMS 17.5 Someone said they way we are doing this is outdated. What is a better way to do this? I thought with SSMS we were kind of stuck.  Thank you.

This is a little example:

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[EMAIL_HoursReport]    Script Date: 2/26/2018 2:03:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EMAIL_HoursReport]   --exec EMAIL_HoursReport @nvRecipients  = 'me@gmail.com'

(
    @nvRecipients as varchar(1000)
)
AS

Declare @nvMessage nvarchar(1000)
Declare @nvSubject nvarchar(1000)
Declare @nvQuery nvarchar(4000)
Declare @iWidth int
Set @iWidth = 4000
Set @nvSubject = ' Hours Report ' 

CREATE TABLE #Data
(
  Hours varchar(50)
, FirstName varchar(50)
, LastName varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Data
SELECT Hours, FirstName, LastName FROM EmpData
WHERE CAST(DateEntered as datetime) = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), GETDATE(),112) AS datetime)
AND Cast(Hours as float) > 10

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Data)
    BEGIN   
        SET @nvquery = 'SELECT Hours, FirstName, LastName FROM #Data' 
        SET @nvMessage = 'Hours Report ' + isnull(' - (' + db_name() + '.dbo.' + object_name(@@procid) + ')', '')
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail_mod
            @recipients = @nvRecipients,
            @subject = @nvSubject,
            @body = @nvMessage,
            @query = @nvQuery
    END
    DROP TABLE #Data
```

Comment: scheduling jobs over `sql agent` is one way. the otherway is over cmd line via `task scheduler`.

Comment: We do use scheduled jobs.  I was more concerned with how I was constructing the email.  Is this the best practice?

Comment: well, in sql you can send html or text format email. up to you.

Comment: They said something about SSRS and it's a lot better.  Is there such a thing? I agree with you, I thought those were my only two options.  HTML is a huge pain.  And forget about attaching Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: agree... yes SSRS should be able to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry but what does that mean? Is that what I'm doing now?

Comment: Using SSRS you create a report, with the query you have now in your stored procedure (only the first part - filling the #Data table) and then you schedule it. SSRS has a scheduler that allows you to send something by email, drop it into a file share and so on. This is I think, [exactly what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318484/dynamically-set-the-to-address-in-ssrs-reports-subscription). Of course, you would provide the email and the actual data to be sent.

Comment: Is this meant to be a follow up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993116/sql-adding-three-separate-tables-to-an-email)?